# Docker Volume missing added file cause container-dir gets user:group from host-dir

Tags: docker

when I run my container with volume option to mount my container-dir `/opt/app/contdir/` to `/absolute/path/hostdir`, I do not find the file **I did copy within a step of of the dockerfile/image**

```
COPY  info.txt /opt/app/contdir/
```

I know the problem is about the ownership of the hostdir which is user1

```
drwxrwxr-x. user1 user1 hostdir
```

while the default-user of the image is root.
When I run the container, I see that the container-dir has taken the ownership from the hostdir.

I do not understand why the **copied file info.txt**  not exist in the contdir and also afterwords in the mounted volume hostdir.

I run the container with the -v option:

docker run -v /absolute/path/hostdir:/opt/app/contdir/ bfd111111111

The container is running fine, the directories are ok, everything works fine, but the initial file info.txt is not there. If I change the ownership of the hostdir to root it also works fine, but I do not want it as root.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

When you mount something into a container, it hides anything that might be there in the image in that place in the file system. I.e. anything in /opt/app/contdir in the image becomes hidden and replaced with what is in the host directory /absolute/path/hostdir

Comment: As I wrote if hostdir and contdir has root:root instead of user1:user1 the file is there. I do not understand the sense of this behaviour